# What's the first movie in which an alien says "We come in peace"?

Tags: history-of, quotes, first-contact

It occurred to me after [yesterday's movie night](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7107/august-movie-event-1) that The Day The Earth Stood Still (1951) is the earliest movie I know of where the alien actually says this.

```
                                  KLAATU
                      We have come to visit you in peace -- 
                      and with good will.
```

**Are there any older movies that also used some variation of "We come in peace"?**

For clarity's sake: I'm after science fiction movies in which an alien comes to Earth and, ideally, the very first thing they say to humanity is a variation of this phrase, since that's the trope I most often see parodied in modern works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## It's *The Day the Earth Stood Still*

After quite a bit of investigation, I can find no instance of an alien uttering this particular phrase (or a variation of it) in any science fiction film prior to 1951's *The Day the Earth Stood Still*.  Of course, it does appear in both fictional and non-fictional works before 1951, but not in the desired context.

I have subsequently concluded that *The Day the Earth Stood Still* **is** the first science fiction film in which a variation of the phrase "we come in peace" is spoken by an alien to a human in a first-contact scenario.

The following article makes for some interesting reading on the different types of first contact presented in early 1950s sci-fi films:

- [Forces of Geek — 1951: The Year Worlds Collided and the Earth Stood Still](http://www.forcesofgeek.com/2013/04/history-of-science-fiction-cinema-1951.html)

Referring to *The Day the Earth Stood Still*, the article proclaims:

> So simple, so archetypal, that it would become the basis for many a future sci-fi film...

In particular, it seems to be the origin of the pervasive "we come in peace" trope in science fiction cinema.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are some of those "fiction and non-fiction works" which have the phrase in other contexts?

Comment: @Ixrec : Non-fiction: political texts, congressional hearings, historical accounts, etc.  Fiction: the 1885 novel *King Solomon's Mines* by H.R. Haggard about an elephant hunter / treasure seeker, and a short story in *Esquire* magazine in 1942.  All of these are either in the context of first contact (between human groups) or peace negotiations.  None involve aliens. ;-)

Comment: I've removed the superfluous image, however if you do wish to rollback please do add an image description.

Comment: For fiction and non-fiction works that used it before The Day the Earth Stood Still, here's a [google book search for "we come in peace" from 1800-1950](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22we+come+in+peace%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1950&tbm=bks)